# Connecting to Ubuntu host not possible

Tags: wireless, networking, ssh, firewall

I have an Ubuntu-Host which is connected via wlan (and for testing to wired net) to a local net. This Ubuntu-Host is not reachable via network by any other clients on the same network.

But:
If I do a ping from the Ubuntu-Host to the client which is attempting the network connection it works and afterswards the client is able to connect to the Ubuntu-Host.

After a short period of time however the connection will be disconnected again by the Ubuntu-Host (for example within an active SSH session). And I have todo the ping-thing again and reestablish the connection.

I have tried:

- Putting Ubuntu-Host in wlan/wired network
- Disabled Ubuntu-Host firewall(s) (also checked iptables)
- Trying different clients on wlan/wired with different OSes (Win7, Win8, ArchLinux, Ubuntu)
- Doesn't occur on Windows on the same machine as the Ubuntu-Host
- Checked routing tables (fine)
- Checked network settings (fine)
- Checked home router (fine)
- Checked arp (not sure)

My guess is that something is broken with the arp cache/network stack, since everything works in general and the connection can be opened for a short period by doing a ping from Ubuntu-Host to X.

Any ideas what can cause this behaviour?

Comment: If I am understanding your question, ssh connects , but after some time it disconnects? If that is the case, the is "normal". Use KeepAlive. See http://embraceubuntu.com/2006/02/03/keeping-ssh-sessions-alive/

Comment: no, ssh was an example. i am not able to connect with anything unless i do the "ping trick". afterwards there is a short time frame which i can use to establish short-lived network connections.

Comment: what wireless card?